# how to manage caching memory in AFNetworking Library

Tags: ios, caching, memory-management, afnetworking

I am developing a content display app in which there is a table view and a detail view corresponding to each row in the table.

There are 12 categories in which content is loaded.

I have completed the app and it is working fine. Now I need to manage memory consumption for cache as I am receiving a warning at run time. I am using AFNetowking lib for caching.

There is no problem in functioning of the app. I just need to do some memory management and apply the code.

I am trying to allocate some particular memory and disk apace for each category.

following is the code that i am using to allocate ram and disk size for each category.

```
NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:15 * 512 * 1024
                                                        diskCapacity:10 * 1024 * 1024
                                                            diskPath:nil];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];
```

xcode version : 6.1
taget ios version : 6.0
app : universal

Comment: Memory warning doesn't necessarily imply it's because of caching. 
NSURLCache purges out all the data when the app receives memory warning. Are you testing on device ? Do you see memory warning when you remove the caching code ? Have you checked instruments to figure out if there is a memory leak ?

Answer (score -1):

I think the recommendation is to not set the size of the cache. The system should take care of that.

I would generally use a common NSCache, and just store data packets based on the URL. And then convert the data back into any image/xml/text whatever I was expecting.

```
    // This should reference an NSCache instance
    _contentCache = [[NSCache alloc] init];

    // create a key for the request.
    cacheKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@|%@",uri,body];
    NSData *cacheData = [_contentCache objectForKey:cacheKey];

    // if its in the cache, just return it.
    if (cacheData) {
        return cacheData;
    }

    // Request the data here and return it.
```

_contentCache is defined in the AppDelegate. So that I can reference it easily from across the app.

```
    - (id) init {

        _appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        _contentCache = [_appDelegate contentCache];

        return self;
    }
```

I've posted my class to GitHub. Its not complete, but its useable.

[postmaster - GitHub](https://github.com/buzzcloudau/postmaster)

Comment: thanks for your response, will think of the solution that you are suggesting.

Comment: You didn't get the question right. NSURLCache does all of these things and much more. The issue is not which caching mechanism to be used. For simple stuff like caching images implementing LRU or FIFO memory cache this solution works the best but wants caching on top of a networking library. NSCache is not designed to do this.